# angularjs with dropdown select

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs, ajax

If I select drop down text display that table using SQL database. please try to solve here my code is now suppose i select one text in drop-down & click on button then display that selected text table using SQL server.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl"> user Roles: <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" ng-model="dropdown">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option data-ng-repeat="Role in RolesList">{{Role.RoleName}}</option>
</select>
  </br></br>
  <input id="Button1" type="button" class="button" value="button" ng-click="click()"  />      </div>

<script>var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope, $http) {               
        $scope.fillList = function () {
            $scope.RoleName = "";
            var httpreq = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetList',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'dataType': 'json'
                },
                data: {}
            }
            $http(httpreq).success(function (response) {
                $scope.RolesList = response.d;                   
            })
        };
        $scope.fillList();           
    });
</script>
```

here my cs code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static List<Names> GetList()
    {
        List<Names> names = new List<Names>();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.42,1433;Initial Catalog=Harneedi;User ID=chaitanya_t;Password=makrotech"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "select RoleName from HN_Master_User_Role";
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
        }
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                names.Add(new Names(dr["RoleName"].ToString()));
        }
        return names;
    }

}
public class Names
{
    public string RoleName;
    public Names(string _RoleName)
    {
        RoleName = _RoleName;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You are calling a `click` behaviour on button click but I can't see that in your controller.

Comment: i dont know how to write click event .plz tell me clcik function event code

Comment: What you want to do when user click the button?

Comment: i want on button clicks display that selected one table thats my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to populate dropdown code looks fine to me. Although you haven't specified what you are trying to do when user clicks the button, I will show how you can get the selected value of dropdown.

You will need to add a behavior in your controller which you can call from button:-

```
$scope.fillList(); 
$scope.click = function (selectedValue) {
                     alert(selectedValue);
                }
```

Then since you are already binding the dropdown selected value using `ng-model="dropdown"` you can use the same while calling this behavior:-

```
 <input id="Button1" type="button" class="button" value="button" 
         ng-click="click(dropdown)" />
```

Comment: thanks it works  on my requirement . But i need selected value , that table taken from database & then display that using .cs

Comment: @chaitanya - This will display `selected value` only. Since in this both `text `& `value` are **same** you are not able to see the difference. Also you are just returning `RoleName`, you are not returning any column which will serve as `value` attribute.

Comment: no i have one more requirement. how to create html table,stored in object that object data is transferred to ng-click function & then display that table

Comment: @chaitanya - That's look like a completely new requirement and its broad too. You will have to post a new question and show what you have already tried.

Comment: @chaitanya - Hey buddy you should thank by accepting the answer that's how this forum works.